# How to use an enum for an array subscript in Java

Tags: java, arrays, enums

How do you use an enum for an array subscript?

```
enum {VALUE_ONE, ... , SIZE};
int[] x = new int[SIZE];
```

Comment: please explain a bit more about your question. Each enum has a static method `values()` to get all its values.and use `ordinal()` to get it's position in enum.

Comment: I want to use a set of constant values with names like in an enum to iterate through an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code. It doesn't look like good practice, though.

```
int[] x = new int[EnumClass.values().length];
```

You can then access the element by `ordinal()`

```
int val = x[enumVar.ordinal()];
```

Still doesn't look like good practice.

Consider using `Map<EnumClass, AtomicInteger>` like `EnumMap<EnumClass, AtomicInteger>`. Why atomic integer? because it can have it's value modified instead of assigning a new instance all the time (at the cost of possibly unnecessary synchronization). That's a different issue though.

Comment: I don't know what you wan't to achieve. `Map<Enum, AtomicInteger>`? You have `EnumMap` designed for enums. I would not depend on enum's ordinal value for any data structure, since it depends entirely on the definition order. Suppose you save the array, modify the enum, and try to read the array. It'll be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) - it was intended for just this case.

```
enum Value {
    VALUE_ONE, ... , VALUE_LAKH
}
Map<Value, Integer> x = new EnumMap<>();
x.put(Value.VALUE_ONE, 13);
```

Internally uses an array (`Integer[]`). The only disadvantage is using `Integer` instead of `int`. And assumedly java 9 or 10 will introduce primitive generic types (`List<int>` and such).

BTW `EnumSet` exists too, and is as efficient as `BitSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Enum is not number. But you can do SIZE.ordinal()

Answer (score 0):

For below enum

```
 enum test{VALUE_ONE, ... , SIZE};
```

Use SIZE like this

```
int[] x = new int[test.SIZE.ordinal()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `int[] x = new int[SIZE.ordinal()]; int var = x[SOME_VALUE.ordinal()];`
Its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero.

Or set special number for each enum elements. like:

```
enum A {
   VALUE_ONE(0),
   SIZE(1),
   ;

   int value;

   private A( int value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public int getValue() {
       return this.value;
   }
}

int[] x = new int[A.SIZE.getValue()];
int var = x[A.VALUE_ONE.getValue()];
```

Comment: When i try System.out.println( x[A.VALUE_ONE.getValue()] ); I get arrayOutOfBoundIndexException

Comment: `VALUE_ONE(0),` `VALUE_TWO(1),` I used these but they both resulted in 0 when printed when `SIZE(2)`

Comment: `int[] x = new int[A.SIZE.getValue()];`
`int var1 = x[A.VALUE_ONE.getValue()];// var1 == 0`
`int var2 = x[A.VALUE_TWO.getValue()];// var2 == 0`

You mean that?

Comment: I set `var = x[A.VALUE_ONE.getValue()]` and then printed `var`. I set `var` equal to the same thing but `VALUE_TWO` this time and they both printed out 0

Comment: did you fill array x? by default arrays fill with zero. your array is represented as `[0, 0]`